# Run Function down column in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have this workable function, not a formula, that I would like to run down columns until there are no more than a blank cell in row "A".

It's supposed to determined what quater the date-data that I have in row "A" is

My function:

```
Function Kvartal(cel)
    Kvartal = Format(cel, "K" & "q" & " - " & "yyyy")

End Function
```

What I have so far

```
Sub Sample()
Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

Set currentSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin")

With currentSheet
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("J2:J" & lRow).Formula = Kvartal
End With
End Sub
```

This sub works fine if it's a formula, but I can't get it to call a function, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are trying to do.

```
With currentSheet
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("J2:J" & lRow).Formula = "=Kvartal(A2)"
End With
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something so piss easy. I just couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to implement a formula through VBA then you can also use:

```
With ActiveSheet
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("J2:J" & lRow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(""K"",ROUNDUP(MONTH(A2)/3,0),"" - "",YEAR(A2))"
End With
```

Custom function is not required.